# PHP Date conversion to SQLSrv

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having some troubles with some SQLSrv dates and PHP. Here is the code:

```
echo date_format($startDate, 'd/m/Y');
echo date_format($endDate, 'd/m/Y');


$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date_format($endDate, 'd/m/Y')));
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date_format($startDate, 'd/m/Y')));
```

The result from the above echo is: `10/10/201613/10/2016` wich is ok because that's what I'm fetching from the Database. But as the code runs I'm using the 2 strings inside a while to insert into Sqlsrv DB again into Date format the `$stardDate`is inserted as `2016-10-10` on all rows which is ok but the `$endDate` is inserted as `1970-01-01`.

Can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: what is $endDate variable value ?

Comment: It's a SQL field on the exact same format as the `$startDate` - 2016-10-13

Comment: Than u must need to check `echo $endDate`

Comment: What is your default date format in SQL Server? MM/DD/YYYY? If so, then you are sending it 13/10/2016 which, 13 is not a valid month.

Comment: @rgomez not talking about format, if you are getting "  `1970-01-01` " as a result it means your `$endDate` is null

Comment: @HabibRehman it can't be because when I run `echo date_format($endDate, 'd/m/Y');` I get 13/10/2016 but after `$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date_format($endDate, 'd/m/Y')));` the $endDate gets null

Comment: Chk end date what r u getting before insert. And second, just for testing as u mentioned start date is fine than insert start date value in end date column u will see the diff

Comment: In this $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date_format($endDate, 'd/m/Y'))); what is the value of $endDate before this line? And after this line?

Comment: It's the correct one 13/10/2016.

Comment: so you just want to format date as Year-Month-Day ??

Comment: The main goal is to get a SQL Date Field that is stored as 2016-10-13 and insert it on another. I've tried doing it directly, doing `$endDate =$fetch['endDate']` and trying to insert $endDate but it fails so that's why I need it converted.

Comment: The error in on the conversion somehow because I tried to put $startDate as 2016-10-13 and it fails also, because 13 is not a valid month.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question the error was on the conversion so I found out I needed to replace / with - here is the code where both strings are returned ok. Thanks @WEI_DBA for pointing me out to that:

```
$endDate = date_format($endDate, 'd/m/Y');
$endDate = str_replace('/', '-', $endDate);
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate));

$startDate = date_format($startDate, 'd/m/Y');
$startDate = str_replace('/', '-', $startDate);
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate));
```